# Is sending direct message to user id using telebot impossible now

Tags: database, psycopg2, telebot

At first the code was working well, I could send a broadcast to all bot users using there IDs stored on a database. But it brings an error now.
**My code**

```
def send_cast(message):
    msg1 = message.text.split(None,1)[1]
    user = message.chat.id
    #start
    conn = connect_to_db()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    db_users = "select user_id from UFM_USERS where type ='VIP'"
    cursor.execute(db_users)
    u = cursor.fetchall()
    users = [row[0] for row in u]
    conn.commit()
    #fetch users
    try:
        if user not in m.admin:
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id,text=f"You require admin permission to do this ‼️",parse_mode = "Markdown")
        else:
            try:
               for user in users:
                bot.send_message(chat_id=users,text=msg1,parse_mode = "Markdown")
            except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as e:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id,text=e,parse_mode = "Markdown")
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as e:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,text=e,parse_mode = "Markdown")
```

It brings an error as:

```
A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found
```

Yet users are retrieves as

```
'1**30**095,5**30**076,9**0**079'
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to the telebot documentation https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.send_message, first argument of `send_message` is either int or str and it is expected to me a single chat_id.

In your code the whole list of `users` is passed to `send_message`:

```
for user in users:
    bot.send_message(chat_id=users,text=msg1,parse_mode = "Markdown")
```

I guess it is a typo, try changing `users` to `user`.